# How to pass POST data from Contact Form 7 to another subpage after submitting the form

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I would like to pass data from **Contact Form 7** to another subpage after submitting the form.
I would like to use the `POST` method for this

- I can get to this data with the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` filter as follows:

```
function cf7_data()
{
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();

    // Here I have a variable containing a field from the contact form
    $subject = $data['your-name'];

    // I don't know what to do next
}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'cf7_data');
```

- I can make redirect after submit form as follows:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'https://samewebsite/subpage';
}, false );
```

but I can't figure out how I can pass and read the `$subject` variable on the subpage after the redirection

Comment: One way to do this would be to start a PHP Session (WP has an API for that) and store it in a session variable.

Comment: I considered using sessions, but Wordpress doesn't use sessions, so I wonder what the consequences of using sessions may be.
I can't find information about this API in the documentation. Where is it?

Comment: I found it here: https://www.ironistic.com/using-php-sessions-in-wordpress/ but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: As I understand by API you mean Wordpress Hooks. I tested it and it works, but as I mentioned, I have doubts about the correctness of this solution. Anyway, thank you for your input